# NULL as a pointer valid address?

Tags: c

Can we assign or compare a valid pointer with 0? where could we assign NULL as legal?
See what I know NULL is a invalid pointer , that pointing to heap memory , which pointer has not freed yet.But is the address of the pointer is valid?

Comment: Too many questions at once.

Comment: The address `0` and a _null pointer_ are distinct values as of the standard. And `0` and the **macro** `NULL` are also different things. Casting an integer to a pointer and the bit-pattern of a null pointer are implementation defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> NULL as a pointer valid address?

Maybe: `NULL` is a macro which expands to a *null pointer constant*.  It *may* have a value like `int` 0. In that case, it is not a pointer but a `int`.  It *may* have a value like `((void*)0)` which *is* a pointer.  When a *null pointer constant* is converted to `void *`, it is a *null pointer*.  **No object will have an address that is equal to a *null pointer***.  The *null pointer* can be assigned to any pointer variable.

> Can we assign or compare a valid pointer with 0?

Yes.  `any_type *ptr = 0;` is valid.  The comparison `if (ptr == 0)` is valid.  The `int` 0 is converted to a *null pointer* as part of the assignment / compare.

> where could we assign NULL as legal?

`any_type *ptr = NULL;` is a legal assignment.

> See what I know NULL is a invalid pointer , that pointing to heap memory , which pointer has not freed yet. But is the address of the pointer is valid?

The address is or is not valid is irrelevant.  Pointing to heap memory or not is irrelevant. In C, assigning a *null pointer* to a pointer variable **is** valid.   Comparing a *null pointer* to a valid object **is** a valid comparison and the result never matches.

Dereferencing a pointer that has the value of a *null pointer* is undefined behavior (UB).  It *may* "work", it *may* crash the code.  It is UB.

Answer (score 1):

No, `NULL` does not denote a valid address in any way. `NULL` is a MACRO which is basically an implementation defined *null pointer constant*.

Related, `C11`, chapter 7.19,

> `NULL`
>   which expands to an implementation-defined null pointer constant

It will compare unequal to any valid pointer and any attempt to derefernce a pointer initialized with `NULL` will result in UB.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.3.2.3

> If a null pointer constant is converted to a
>   pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal
>   to a pointer to any object or function.

Comment: `NULL` is a macro name. You hardly can dereference it ...

Comment: Problem is on typical systems which use a zero bit-pattern to represent a pull pointer **and** have a valid address `0` the comparison will succeed, thus strictly violating the standard.

Comment: "***pull** pointer*" is a nice type/o ... ;-) @Olaf

Comment: @alk: :) Hey, there are just few key between `n` and `p` on my keyboard. But more modern are actually _rush pointers_ ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` is the null pointer constant, it's value is implementation defined, that is to say, it is not necessarily being 0.

According to the C11 standard,

> Conversion of a null pointer to another pointer type yields a null pointer of that type. Any two null pointers shall compare equal.

In addition, assign integers to pointers is implementation defined, you should not rely on it if you want to make portable code.

> An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.

Comment: `0` or any _integer constant expression_ yielding `0` is a special thing. Permanent cause of trouble and confusion.

Comment: Yes, right, I agree.

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` is by definition an invalid pointer. But. On most systems pointers are just numbers that we give a special treatment. Until a while ago (maybe a decade or so) it was possible on some operating systems to forcibly map memory at the address where a NULL pointer pointed.

This led to a dangerous situation where the operating system kernel could have a relatively harmless bug that led to a NULL dereference and normally just crash. But instead, if a malicious program forcibly mapped memory at the NULL address and then triggered the kernels NULL dereference, it would point to valid memory and if done correctly it could escalate a simple system crash to a kernel level privilege escalation.

There was a bug in Linux where a driver could be fooled into executing a NULL function pointer and that allowed a malicious program to put code at that address that the kernel would execute with raised privileges.

Since then most operating systems have tightened their security and disallow mapping any valid memory at the addresses at and close to NULL ("close to" to protect against array access with a large offset through a NULL pointer).

Comment: Detail: `NULL` is not necessarily a pointer.  By C definition it is "`NULL`
which expands to an implementation-defined null pointer constant;"  When converted to a pointer type, `void *`,the result is a _null pointer_.